# MKMapView not loading

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to load a MKMapView (initiated in the storyboard) and all it shows is a bunch of grid lines (boxes?).

[image]

I also noticed that my iOS simulator does not have internet access even though the computer has internet access.

[image]

Can someone point me towards what could be wrong?

Comment: Try quitting the simulator & starting it again. I know it sounds silly but my simulator has been losing its connection quite a bit since going to Xcode 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try quitting the simulator & starting it again. I know it sounds silly but my simulator has been losing its connection quite a bit since upgrading to Xcode 6.

Comment: I have the same issue in the device